# jax-rs routing priority conflicts

Tags: java, routes, jax-rs

I'm using jax-rs with Spring. I have 2 PUT APIs, which have a conflict, and I want to give priority to one of them.

```
@PUT
@Path("/allQuestions")
public Response method1() {}

@PUT
@Path("/{qustionId}")
public Response method2(@PathParam("qustionId") long qustionId) {}
```

When I call `/allQuestions`, the application always tries to insert the 'allQuestions' string into the `qustionId` of `method2`, so I want to give priority to `method1`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've tested with with three different implementations (included JAX-RS 1 & 2 for both Jersey and Resteasy), and **alll** hit the first method, as expected. Even the JAX-RS specifies that the first method should always get hit (as it has literal characters).

Comment: I suggest you do **All** of these things in this order. **(1)** Test the actual code you are posting. **(2)** If you still getting the same result, post enough information for us to reproduce it (i.e. implementation, complete class, app configuration, server, etc.). **(3)** If it is not a problem with the code you posted, then post the actual code. **(4)** Post exactly how you are calling/consuming this resource, meaning the client and steps/code we should take to reproduce the problem, along with other important details from step 2.

Comment: As far design does, personally, I would get rid of the `@Path("/allQuestions")` altogether. if the class `@Path`, is `/questions`, then the collection of questions could just be accessed by `../questions`, instead of `../questions/allQuestions`. `../questions`, semantically speaking, already means "all questions".

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your help(it really helped), I've posted the answer below to what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing `@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })` line before method1. The full code was:

```
@PUT
@Path("/availableQuestions")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response method1() {}

@PUT
@Path("/{questionId}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response method2(@PathParam("questionId") long questionId) {}
```

I'm not sure why(**edit:** see @peeskillet comment for an explanation), but now that I've added `@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })`:

```
@PUT
@Path("/availableQuestions")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response method1() {}
```

It just works.

Comment: There is an algorithm that goes into determining the chosen method. Included as a factor is the media type. Since both method match the path, the media type is checked next. Since `method2` is more specific (with application/json, that one will win. Without the annotation on `method1`, its like saying _any_ media type. The most specific always wins.

Comment: @peeskillet I guessed its something like that, but your explanation really clarified things. Thanks.